# Ошибка 404 при запуске Spring MVC (самое простое приложение) Eclipse

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring-mvc, eclipse, tomcat

error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Помогите разобраться.. использую Tomcat 9.0.65 IDE Eclipse
структура:
[image: структура]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.company.springcourse</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-mvc-app1</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>spring-mvc-app1 Maven Webapp</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>
 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
   <spring.version>5.3.22</spring.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.11</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.M2</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-app1</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
   
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-mvc-app1</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering/>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContextMVC.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.springcourse"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" 
class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
    package com.company.springcourse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

hello_wprld.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My app</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно причина либо в том, что приложение по какой-то причине не запустилось, либо приложение находится по другому URL (например, "localhost:8080/my-app/", а не "localhost:8080/".

Возможно, контекст Spring не смог подняться из-за исключения (в логах можно найти warning)

Comment: я про context path знаю . поменял на "/" . А первую причину как можно исправить? не совсем понял в каких логах

Comment: В логах приложения или самого Tomcat'а (в папке logs).

Comment: Под логами приложения понимаю, например, Logback или Log4j.
Но суть в том, что приложение возможно не запускается из-за ошибки. В этом случае Tomcat молча отвечает с кодом 404.

Comment: нет в логах не было warning . уже решил проблему . когда нажимаешь 2 раза на tomcat , там в вкладке Module должен быть список проектов, а у меня ничего там не было ,так как я ранее очистил tomcat, возможно поэтому

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кому то пригодится.
Для того чтобы изменить `localhost:8080/app_name` на `localhost:8080/` в eclipse нужно

1. Project > Properties > Web Project Settings > и указать `Conrext root: /`.

2.В вкладке servers 2 раза нажать на tomkat > Modules > и изменяете Path вашего модуля на `/` , а если там ничего нет(например после очистки сервера, как было у меня) ,то нужно выбирать Add Web Mudule > выбрать ваше приложение и потом уже указать Path на `/`
P.S. если во вкладке Modules (из второго пункта) ничего не будет ваше приложение не будет работать и выдаст error 404. обязательно проверьте.Из-за этого много часов потратил